# error 1045 (28000) access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, command-line, root

Please forgive me for being a complete beginner:

I am trying to log into my very first mySQL database that I installed using easyPHP on my windows machine, using the cmd line. I am going to the \mysql\bin and entering the command:

```
mysql -u root
```

in order to log in, but I am getting the following message:

```
error 1045 (28000) access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Why is it using the password "YES"? Shouldn't there be no password at all? Do I need to restart mySQL or something? If so, how do I do that? If it's relevant, I did try to create the database using phpmyadmin, but had a few problems entering columns and decided I'd be better off working from the command line so I could learn all the commands as I went along.

Please keep in mind that this is my first time ever trying to work with a database, so be kind to me!

Comment: "using password: YES" means that you are using a password, not that "YES" is that password.

Comment: 1045 error explained here: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have mysql asking you for a password, you also need to specify the `-p`-option:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Is there somewhere I can learn more about the various commands and things I need to use terminals? Are they significantly different for Windows and Linux?

Comment: No, the commands aren't different for the `mysql` command line client on Windows or Linux. But they can differ from version to version (of `mysql`). I think you should read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html On Linux you can also use `man mysql` to get a quick overview.

Comment: Just a note for Mac users that if you change your root password, this login command uses whatever password you set within mysql, not your Mac's root password.

Comment: @Kelseydh This is true for any OS, not just Mac.

Answer (score 3):

When logging into MYSQL using the command line, you also have to specify the password if any. Your error message is telling you that the user "root" has a password attached to it. Not necessarily that the password is "YES" when you were installing easyPHP, it should have either provided you with a default password or allowed you to enter a password of your choosing.

According to the documentation of easyPHP:

> [v1.6] My scripts worked perfectly with 1.5 but now I get this error : Warning: Forbidden access for user: 'user@localhost' (password: YES) when I want to connect to MySql.
>
> Only the root user (without password) has the rights to connect to the database. Either modify your scripts to use it, or add the user you need (phpMyAdmin/users and privileges: See phpMyAdmin's documentation for more information).

`mysql -u root -p`

Now if you changed your root user password, you will need to specify that when prompted. Otherwise simply hit `<Enter>` on your keyboard.

If you FORGOT the password to root, and have changed it, you will have to subsequently reinstall easyPHP.

Comment: "If you FORGOT the password to root, and have changed it, you will have to subsequently reinstall easyPHP." If you have forgotten your MySQL-root-password, you'll need to reinstall MySQL, not easyPHP…

Comment: With easyPHP, I don't think you can just reinstall MySQL. Most of the suites don't install just PHP, MySQL, etc individually but as a collective group. If you just installed MySQL, PHP, and say Apache separately, then yes, you would just reinstall MySQL. In the users case, he installed MySQL as a part of easyPHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
agk-hp:~/$mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'greg'@'localhost' (using  password: NO)
agk-hp:~/$sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf|grep password
 password = t7753my3D2x4yfQm

agk-hp:~/$mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p  
Enter password: {t7753my3D2x4yfQm} 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

mysql> use mysql;

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'greg'@'localhost';


agk-hp:~/$mysql
mysql>
```

Comment: Maybe give a little detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A modification for mysql- 5.7.10 on mac mac el capitan

- sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
- sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

  Now open new window/tab on terminal and type
- "mysql -u root"
- use mysql
- update user set authentication_string=password('yourpassword') where user='root';