# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes) after password reset LINUX

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration

I have a MySQL installed on my linux server, I forgot it's password so I went and changed it using the methods I found on the web. What I did was as follows:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql --user root mysql
SELECT * FROM user; // I checked if I could access the user table or not
update user SET password = PASSWORD('new_pass') WHERE user = 'root';
flush privileges;
exit
```

The update query did change the password as it showed me the number of rows affected and Query OK etc.

Then I restarted mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Now when I logged in with the new password

```
mysql -u root -p new_pass
```

it still gives me errors 
**"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes)"**

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I took a closer look at the user table in mysql database, turns out someone prior to me edited the ssl_type field for user root to SSL.

I edited that field and restarted mysql and it worked like a charm.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to start MySql in safe mode. It does not require root password. Once you login, you will be in mysql database, you can then issue a select * from user and see the fields for yourself.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to solve this problem by executing this statement

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

Which will change the root password.

Answer (score 7):

You have to reset the password! steps for mac osx(tested and working) and ubuntu

Stop MySQL

```
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Start it in safe mode:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

(above line is the whole command)

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, log in without a password:

```
$ mysql -u root

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

Start MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

your new password is 'password'.

Comment: Just two different things: To stop the server, I had to go to System Preferences -> MySQL; From MySQL 5.7 there is no password column in the users table - authentication_string is the new column ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/31122246/782874 )

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. You have to write `mysql -u root -p`

NOT `mysql` or `mysql -u root -p root_password`

Comment: This worked for me, albeit i referred to http://askubuntu.com/questions/428243/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem, @[progrAmmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2481666/programmar) enlightened me, "**took a closer look at the user table in mysql database**".

My problem is not **ssl_type**, instead of the first field：**Host**. I changed the value by using

`update user set Host='localhost' where User='root' and Host='%';`

in `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` model.

Then it works well.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to clear the `plugin` column for your root account. On my fresh install, all of the root user accounts had `unix_socket` set in the `plugin` column. This was causing the root sql account to be locked only to the root unix account, since only system root could login via socket.

If you `update user set plugin='' where User='root';flush privileges;`, you should now be able to login to the root account from any localhost unix account (with a password).

See [this AskUbuntu question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672008/cant-login-to-mysql-as-root-anymore) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

On mac os, please follow below steps:

Stop MySQL

$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
Start it in safe mode:

$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
(above line is the whole command)

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, log in without a password:

$ mysql -u root

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
Start MySQL

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
your new password is 'password'.

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

1. /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

(in new window)

3. mysql -u root
4. mysql> use mysql;
5. mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';
6. mysql>flush privileges;
7. mysql> quit
8. /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the current user is not root，try sudo mysql -uroot -p ,I successed just now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution :-

To have mysql asking you for a password, you also need to specify the -p-option: (try with space between -p and password)

```
mysql -u root -p new_password
```

[MySQLl access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382219/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-ye)

In the [Second link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/how-to-reset-forgot-mysql-root-password-on-unix-linux-windows/) someone has commented the same problem.