# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a Java application and I want to access my local database which is a MySQL database, but I have this exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried to execute this command from MySQL command line client:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPass';
```

But it didn't solve my problem and the exception still appears.

This my connection configuration "database.properties" file:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/mydb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=myPass
```

Comment: You omitted your connection config.

Comment: @Tiny i tried to connect with these username and password from MySQL Query Browser and i Succeeded

Comment: You need to feed the admin user name and password in jdbc. That is a possible explanation and could you also share a bit of code.

Comment: i post my 'database.properties' file

Comment: @Maverick , root is the only user

Comment: Following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533441/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-password-r) seems to cover your issue. Either reset root password or change ssl_type field for user root.