# MySQL, cannot connect to Database due to "root"@"localhost" access denial

Tags: mysql

So, i'm trying to do homework with MySQL Workbench on Xubuntu, I got schema on my local machine, and I need to do Forward Engeneer to DB. When I click "Next" on the page "Set options for DB to be created", it shows me a window and asking to enter root password. When I do, it shows me error message:

Connect to Database

> Error connecting to database:
>
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

And I cannot finish forwarding to start working with terminal. What's wrong?

Comment: check if below 2 links help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533441/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-password-r  and http://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: @narendra Yes, it worked. Thank you very much!