# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I went through all similar or identical questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533441/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-password-r), for ex.) but still can't solve the problem.

I am on Xenial and have MySQL 5.7.12. I do not remember setting any password during installation (if it asked, I provided empty one).

I tried to go through password reset using `--skip-grant-tables`, as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html), it updated the database row, but I still cannot login.

Reconfiguring with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` doesn't do anything, I get this:

```
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.12, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.7
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.12, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Any ideas?

Comment: terminal, `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper re-installing helped. Removed everything associated ([this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/uninstall-mysql-completely), but it is important to specify the version of mysql, e.g. `apt-get --yes purge mysql-server-5.7 mysql-client-5.7`, and I also deleted mysql-common and all dependencies to be sure).

Then installed again (`apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`) and when it asked for a password, this time, I gave it one. It works now.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL 5.7 generates a random root password by itself on installation.

This was a new change in MySQL 5.7.4, and described in the release notes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-4.html

> The installation process creates only a single root account,
>   'root'@'localhost', automatically generates a random password for this
>   account, and marks the password expired. The MySQL administrator must
>   connect as root using the random password and use SET PASSWORD to
>   select a new password. (The random password is found in the
>   .mysql_secret file in the home directory of the effective user running
>   the script.)

I never find the .mysql_secret file, but the random password is also output in the MySQL error log (e.g. /var/log/mysqld.log on Linux). The notice looks like this:

```
2016-07-11T15:59:54.922316Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: f14_W1lN7FfP
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either reinstall everything, which i did. I had initially installed using macos package installer. That didn't get me anywhere.

So uninstalled everything, then upgraded brew, and installed via brew. Running the mysql shell proved a messy affair. Ultimately what worked was `mysql -u root -p`.

I was running it on localhost, so turns out root password wasn't required. Weirdly, `mysql -u root -p <password>` threw the "access denied" message.