# centos 7 mariadb - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mariadb, slurm

I have this problem in my centos 7 and my database mariadb:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: No)

when i try to run this program :

```
systemctl start slurmdbd
```

I already tried to use this solution but it doesn't work for me:
[Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes) after password reset LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533441/access-denied-for-user-)

```
mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

I also tried to reconfigure mariadb with mysql_secure_installation and create 'root' user with 'root' password.

But it's not working. Is there another solution?

Comment: Can you get in with `mysql -u root -p` and then enter the pwd at the subsequent prompt?

Comment: yes, i enter password and i havez access to mariaDB console

Comment: The error message implie that you are not using `-p`??

Comment: Connect with sudo, I mean, after change the password run: sudo `mysql -u root -p`. I have been the same issue in Debian 9.4, and after change the password and connecting with sudo, it was connected without any problem. I hope it could be helpful.